# why not update the picture? laravel 5.4

Tags: image, laravel, upload

I can upload a picture, but when I try to update it, then there is no error. The file name changes in the database to the name of the new picture. And in the public folder the picture remains old and does not appear new.

**I use: Intervention Image**

*What I did not understand, help please.*

**Controller: UploadController**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Post;
use Image;
use Storage;
use Faker\Provider\File;

public function update (Request $request, $id)
{
    //validate
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'author' => 'required',
        'text' => 'required',
        'desc' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',
    ]);
    $posts = Post::find($id);
    $posts->title = $request->input('title');
    $posts->author = $request->input('author');
    $posts->text = $request->input('text');
    $posts->desc = $request->input('desc');
    $posts->image = $request->input('image');

    //update image
    if ($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('images/'. $filename);
        Image::make($image)->resize(800, 400)->save($location);
        $oldFilename = $posts->image;
        //update db
        $posts->image = $filename;
        //delete old image
        Storage::delete($oldFilename);
    }
    $posts->save();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

**View: edit.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('goUpdate', [$posts->id]) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {!!  method_field('patch') !!}
    @if($posts)
        <div class="form-group">
            <br>
            <label>title</label>
            <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $posts->title }}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>author</label>
            <input name="author" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $posts->author }}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>text</label>
            <textarea name="text" class="form-control" rows="7">{{ $posts->text }}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>desc</label>
            <textarea name="desc" class="form-control" rows="5">{{ $posts->desc }}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>image</label>
            <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control-file" value="" >
        </div>
        <div>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="update"/>
            <a href="{{ url('/') }}" class="btn btn-primary">back</a>
        </div>
    @endif
</form>
<br>
```

**filesystems.php**

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('images/'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
$image = $request->file('image');
$filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
$path = public_path('events/' . $filename);
Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(300, 300)->save($path);
$event->image = 'events/' . $filename;
```

Hope this can help you

Comment: All the same, only I did not understand why you need a variable $event and a new directory 'events/'

Comment: yeah because I save it into public/events directory.. Have you tried to remove `if ($request->hasFile('image'))` ?.. or maybe you can return the value of image.. maybe the value is `null` @Иван

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I just forgot to write in the file View: edit.blade.php in the form tag: enctype="multipart/form-data 
But now another problem, the old picture is not deleted.

Comment: why the old picture is not deleted? @Иван

Comment: I do not understand, just a new picture appears, a way is prescribed and normally everything displays, but the old one remains. It's very strange, although the code is completely written.